# repeative partial reads using html5 file APIs

Tags: javascript, html

I do NOT want to read the ENTIRE contents of a file into memory; only parts of it, and only on demand.

Yet, It seems I can read a chunk ONLY ONCE (using  a `file.slice()`), while all following reads return zero-length. Any ideas?

Here is a simplified sample of the code that fails on 2nd call:

```
var chunkNo=0;
function readNextChunk()
{
  var file=document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).files[0];
  var blob=file.slice(100*chunkNo, 100); 
  var reader=new FileReader();
  reader.onload=function(e) { console.log("No"+chunkNo+":\n"+reader.result);  
    chunkNo++;
  };
  reader.readAsText(blob);
}
```